# Intercepting and changing the return value of a static native method with byte-buddy (System.nanoTime())

Tags: java, instrumentation, byte-buddy, nanotime

I want to change what happens when `System.nanoTime()` is called for arbitrary Java programs (I want to shift back time to help container checkpoint/restore use cases). Whenever `System.nanoTime()` is called, I want to run the original `System.nanoTime()` and then possibly return a different value. I'm trying to use byte-buddy and a JVM instrumentation agent to do this (as per [here](https://tersesystems.com/blog/2016/01/19/redefining-java-dot-lang-dot-system/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487148/redefine-rebase-native-method)).

Here is my attempt:

```java
public final class TimeShifter {
    private TimeShifter() {}

    private static final Class<?> INTERCEPTOR_CLASS = TimeShiftedSystem.class;

    public static void premain(String _arg, Instrumentation instrumentation) throws Exception {
        injectBootstrapClasses(instrumentation);
        new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
                .with(AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.NoOp.INSTANCE)
                .with(AgentBuilder.TypeStrategy.Default.REDEFINE)
                .ignore(
                        new AgentBuilder.RawMatcher.ForElementMatchers(
                                ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith("net.bytebuddy.")
                                        .or(ElementMatchers.isSynthetic())
                                        .or(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith("my.package.name.")),
                                ElementMatchers.any(),
                                ElementMatchers.any()))
                .with(
                        new AgentBuilder.Listener.Filtering(
                                new StringMatcher("java.lang.System", StringMatcher.Mode.EQUALS_FULLY),
                                AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemOut()))
                .type(ElementMatchers.named("java.lang.System"))
                .transform((builder, type, classLoader, module) ->
                        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487148/redefine-rebase-native-method
                        builder.method(ElementMatchers.named("nanoTime"))
                        .intercept(Advice.to(TimeShiftedSystem.class)))
                .installOn(instrumentation);
    }

    private static void injectBootstrapClasses(Instrumentation instrumentation) throws IOException {
        File temp = Files.createTempDirectory("tmp").toFile();
        temp.deleteOnExit();

        ClassInjector.UsingInstrumentation.of(
                        temp, ClassInjector.UsingInstrumentation.Target.BOOTSTRAP, instrumentation)
                .inject(Collections.singletonMap(
                        new TypeDescription.ForLoadedType(INTERCEPTOR_CLASS),
                        ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.read(INTERCEPTOR_CLASS)));
    }
}
```

and

```java
public final class TimeShiftedSystem {
    private TimeShiftedSystem() {}

    @Advice.OnMethodExit
    public static long nanoTime(@Advice.Return long originalReturnValue) {
        System.out.println("originalReturnValue = " + originalReturnValue);

        return originalReturnValue - 1000;
    }
}
```

but this fails with:

```
[Byte Buddy] DISCOVERY java.lang.System [null, module java.base, loaded=true]
[Byte Buddy] ERROR java.lang.System [null, module java.base, loaded=true]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call super (or default) method for public static native long java.lang.System.nanoTime()
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.SuperMethodCall$Appender.apply(SuperMethodCall.java:133)
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Other stuff I've tried:

- Using `MethodDelegation.to` instead of `Advice.to` then calling `System.nanoTime()` inside `TimeShiftedSystem#nanoTime()` - this seems to call the original nanoTime the first time, but immediately goes into a stackoverflow.
- Using `MethodDelegation.to` instead of `Advice.to` and `@Origin Method method` as a parameter. Doesn't seem to get invoked at all (not invoked if the `@RuntimeType` annotation is also used).
- Using `enabledNativeMethodPrefix("native")` - does nothing.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to set

```java
    .with(AgentBuilder.TypeStrategy.Default.REBASE)
    .enableNativeMethodPrefix("native")
```

on the `AgentBuilder` rather than `agentBuilder.TypeStrategy.Default.REDEFINE` (and adding `'Can-Set-Native-Method-Prefix': true` to my jar manifest). This allowed me to get the `TimeShiftedSystem` to work with this Advice:

```
@Advice.OnMethodExit
public static void nanoTime(@Advice.Return(readOnly = false) long returnValue) {
    System.out.println("Called with " + returnValue);
    returnValue = 42;
}
```

Comment: Note that your method is a JVM intrinsic. The behavior might be a bit unpredictable sometimes.

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter: Sounds ominous... what kind of unpredictable behaviour might be seen, do you think?

Comment: The JVM replaces such native method calls with inlined symbols and does not dispatch them. If an alternative JVM implementation resolves such symbols without backtracing them later, the redefinition would not be applied. It's more of a gut feeling. JVMTI is one of the more buggy APIs in the JVM and I'd avoid these sorts of things from expierence as they are really easy to get wrong.

Comment: It looks like you were right to be worried - it does behave unpredictably. From what I can tell, it sometimes it seems to inlines the call, which is very bad for the services I'm trying to checkpoint and restore. Luckily, ensuring `-XX:CompileCommand=dontinline,java/lang/System.nanoTime` seems to fix this problem!

Comment: `System.nanoTime()` may be called by critical JRE code which doesn’t like your changes. A better approach would be to instrument the callers to invoke your replacement method. Then, you can control precisely which classes will be affected and also don’t need the dontinline command.

Comment: Holger: that sounds like a better approach, can byte buddy do this? I would also need JRE classes that use `System.nanoTime()` like `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` to pick up the changes (in fact, this is by far the one I care about the most).

Comment: Have a look at MemberSubstitution which can replace method calls with alternative invokations.

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter: Thanks for the pointer - I've spent a decent amount of time trying to see how I can adapt my existing code to perform the `MemberSubstitution` as part of an agent. I found your previous answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57812921/139766, but I can't work out where to add this an `AgentBuilder.Default()` to rewrite the method calls on every single class (or even to put it in a place that typechecks). Would it be possible to get a hint/example?

Comment: You would need to know somewhat what classes to instrument, i.e. in what classes you would like to apply the transformation. Worst case, you have to transform all classes, unfortunately which will result in a noop in many cases. In the class, apply the substitution the same way you would apply your advice via the `builder.visit` method.

Comment: How odd.  Shouldn't your advice return the modified `long`?

Comment: Ha! I was wrong.  So Byte Buddy must be stealing the generated code rather than actually calling the static.  Interesting...